# Why is this simple service not starting?

Tags: android, service

I have a service with a handler that has to write "Hello" in the logcat every 5 seconds. But it doesn't write nothing on the logcat... It's like the service is not executing, and I put a breakpoint on it and the debug mode never stops on the breakpoint.

I start the service, in the first activity of my app, with this:

```
startService(new Intent(GPSLoc.this, MyServiceNotifications.class)); //enciendo el service
```

I am sure that the code `startService` is executed because it is called before starting another activity, and the other activity starts.

This is the code of my service:

```
public class MyServiceNotifications extends Service {

    boolean serviceStopped;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (serviceStopped == false)
            {
                createNotificationIcon();
            }
            queueRunnable();
        }
    };

    private void queueRunnable() {
        // 600000 : cada 10 minutos, comprueba si hay nuevas notificaciones y actualiza la
        // notification BAR
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 5000);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        serviceStopped = false;

        // //////////////////////////////////////MANEJADOR SIMILAR A UN HILO
        mHandler = new Handler();
        queueRunnable();
        // ///////////////////////////////////// FIN MANEJADOR
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        serviceStopped = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    }

    public void createNotificationIcon()
    {
        Log.d("MyServiceNotifications", "Hello");
    }    
}
```

Comment: did you declare the service in the manifest file?

Comment: put a logcat inside onCreate(), does that get used? Also, when are you calling run()on updateRunnable? I can't see that getting executed

Comment: ohh true, i forgive to put in the maNIFEST!! thanks

Comment: Also one more thing to check is if your service is NOT running already.
In that case you need to stop service and start again.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Did you declare the service in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb now :)  I'm surprised there's no error logged when this happens like it does for Activities.

Comment: The gasp one makes when he realises that he forgot something so simple, especially after scrolling up and down the code for hours... lol.

Comment: It also needs to be declared within the <application ... <application/> section. Don't ask me how I found out....

Comment: <application>
    ....
    <service android:name=".MyServiceNotifications"/>
</application>
As answered by VenkaReddy.

Answer (score 70):

**Very important:** write the **name space** correctly, for example:

```
<service android:name="com.example.data.synchronization.SynchronizationService"/>
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml` previously it was (wrong):

```
<service android:name="com.example.data.SynchronizationService"/>
```

**No service started** and **no error message**!

Comment: Embarassed to admit it but I spent an hour fussing with things before I realized this was the issue for me as well.

Comment: Maybe Android Studio will have more emphasis in recognizing this kind of issues...

Comment: @Jared  same here buddy

Comment: @Jared Just courious, are you using Android Studio or Eclipse? Do you compile with Gradle?

Comment: I was using Eclipse at the time. With the Beta release of Android Studio my company will be making the migration once we tag a new release of our apps in the upcoming days.

Comment: I've just lost a couple of hours on this - had it declared but the wrong namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Hi the code you write is working fine. May be you forgot to add the following code in the manifest file before closing application tag.

```
<application>
    ....
    <service android:name=".MyServiceNotifications"/>
</application>
```

Comment: My vote is for "before closing application tag."  Programmers do silly mistakes!

Comment: This would show up if you run Analyze...Inspect Code in the manifest.

Answer (score 9):

There are also circumstances where you need to put the "enabled" attribute to "true" when defining it in the manifest, like so:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyServiceNotifications" />
```

See this link for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: "The default value is `true`."

Comment: Unless stated differently in another manifest file

Answer (score 3):

If using Xamarin Droid the easiest way to do this is to mark the class as a service like this:

```
[Service]
public class LongRunningTaskService : Service
{
    ...
}
```

Then there's no need to put it in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Very rare case scenario. But when wroking on multiprocess application the activity and the service need to have `android:process` mentioned in the `Manifest.xml`

EG:
RemoteServiceBindingActivity.kt

```
startService(Intent(this, RemoteService::class.java))
```

Then

```
<activity
    android:name=".RemoteServiceBindingActivity"
    android:process=":test" />


<service
    android:name=".RemoteService"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

Didn't work. I had to add `android:process=":test"` to the service too in the Manifest like this:

```
<service
    android:name=".RemoteService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":test"/>
```