# Android Service not started

Tags: android

I am creating a service in my applicatoin.
Here is the code i used.

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.e("Location Service", "onStrat of service");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("Location Service", "onCreate of service");
    LocationOperations locationOperations = new LocationOperations(getBaseContext());
    locationOperations.retrieveLocation();
}
```

}

Also define in the manifest file within the applicatoin tag

```
<service android:name=".LocationService"
         android:process=":LocationService">
    </service>
```

Calling this Service in onCreate method of the Activity

```
Context context = this;
    Intent service = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    service.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(service);
```

But this service is not started.I can't see any Log message in LogCat Window 
Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759676/why-is-this-simple-service-not-starting

Comment: why are you creating your service in a separate process ??

Comment: Beacause i want to get Location coordinates through GPS,WIFI or Cell Tower if any one of available continously until the application is close. so i wanted to run in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                                //do stuff when service disconnected
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                                //do stuff when service connected
                }
            };


context.bindService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class), serviceConnection ,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

onStart() is deprecated, override [OnStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) instead , that should be the function thats called when you call startActivity().

Also, im not sure why you added the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your intent. I dont think its needed here.