# Android can't find my BroadcastReceiver. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a Service that will start on boot.

**I'm seeing the following error in adb:**

```
05-31 10:14:24.060 E/AndroidRuntime( 1583):java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyBootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyBootReceiver" on path: /data/app/MyNameSpace.MyClass-1.apk
05-31 10:14:24.060 E/AndroidRuntime( 1583): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyBootReceiver" on path: /data/app/MyNameSpace.MyClass-1.apk
```

The thing is, I can *definitely* see that the `MyBootReceiver` class exists in `MyNameSpace`, as a subclass of `MyClass`, so it looks like it *should* be able to find it.

**My Manifest is defined as:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="MyNamespace.MyClass">
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

  <application>
    <receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"></activity>

  </application>    
</manifest>
```

**and this is the code:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.xamarin.MyClass" })]
    public class MyClass : IntentService
    {
        private IBinder binder;

        public const string MyUpdatedAction = "MyUpdated";

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            var myIntent = new Intent(MyUpdatedAction);

            SendOrderedBroadcast(myIntent, null);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            binder = new MyServiceBinder(this);
            return binder;
        }

        [BroadcastReceiver]
        [IntentFilter(new string[] { MyUpdatedAction }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
        public class MyBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent)
            {
                Log.Info("MyTrace", "MyReceiver OnReceive action: " + intent.Action);

                if (intent.Action.Contains("BOOT_COMPLETED"))
                {
                    var pushIntent = new Intent(MyUpdatedAction);
                    context.StartService(pushIntent);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this thing working?

Answer (score 0):

I usually add the entire class path when describing items in the manifest file. So in your case I would write:

```
<application>
    <receiver android:name="MyNamespace.MyBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<activity android:name="MyNamespace.MyActivity"></activity>
```

It could be the same problem as [Why is this simple service not starting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759676/why-is-this-simple-service-not-starting/11648668#11648668).

Comment: thanks - should that be `MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyBootReceiver` instead of `MyNameSpace.MyBootReceiver`?

Comment: ..just tried.. prepending the namespace doesn't help. In fact, it complicates things worse, e.g. `Unable to instantiate receiver MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyBootReceiver`

Comment: @DaveDev, I suspect that you have period as first character in your name declaration.

Comment: I do - if I don't have the period I get a deployment error: `Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/MyNamespace.MyClass-Signed.apk Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and found out the solution. Follow the below steps to make your "inner" BroadcastReceiver work without any crash:

1) Make your mainActivity look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements SomeListener {
        MyReceiver myRecvr;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           myRecvr = new MyReceiver();  
           .......
        }

    ...onResume() code ... onPause() code ... yourBroadcastReceiver Class{} ...


}
```

2) Register your receiver in onResume() and Unregister your receiver in onPause() like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume()");
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("MyBroadcast");

    registerReceiver(myRecvr, filter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause()");
    unregisterReceiver(myRecvr);
    super.onPause();
}
```

3) Now add your inner BroadcastReceiver right below onPause() or before your mainActivity class ends like this:

```
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if(extras.containsKey("value")){
                Log.e("BroadcastedValue",extras.get("value").toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Finally, make sure you have added your inner BroadcastReceiver path to manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.yourproject.YourMainActivityName$MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MyBroadcast" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```