# android java service not working

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to create a service in my android project.but the service seems not starting at all.

```
package serviceexample.javatechig.com.serviceexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }
}
```

manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="serviceexample.javatechig.HelloService" android:exported="false"/>
```

and main activity:

```
package serviceexample.javatechig.com.serviceexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        findViewById(R.id.start_service).setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, HelloService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.stop_Service).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, HelloService.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

no errors but when I press the buttons the service won't get started.onCreate and onStartCommand events not raising.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this simple service not starting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759676/why-is-this-simple-service-not-starting)

Comment: look at the second answer: "Very important: write the name space correctly..."

Comment: I'm new in java.do you know what is the correct name?

Comment: I suppose the Service is in the same package, so just write <service android:name=".HelloService" android:exported="false"/>

Comment: @0X0nosugar the path is wrong

Comment: How exactly do you notice that onCreate() hasn't run? The method implementation is empty.

Comment: @ColdFire - well, without the whole Manifest I was just guessing. My bad.

Comment: debug marker doesn't stop on the event and adding Log doesn't show anything in the console.That's how I notice the problem exists Egor

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong package name in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Replace:

```
serviceexample.javatechig.HelloService
```

with

```
serviceexample.javatechig.com.serviceexample.HelloService
```

Basically the path name should be same for service activities and all

Comment: not working. and not working with ".HelloService". I think it's not the manifest.xml

Comment: did you replace in the manifest file right , serviceexample.javatechig.HelloService?

Comment: also remove the exported attribute

Comment: I added "Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");;" in the onStartCommand event but nothing happens even when removed the exported attriviute.

Comment: use log.e @amirmola

Comment: no difference. the Log is showing when i put it in the main activity but not in the service

Answer (score 0):

The package your `Service` is in:

```
package serviceexample.javatechig.com.serviceexample;
```

The class name you use in the Manifest:

```
<service android:name="serviceexample.javatechig.HelloService" android:exported="false"/>
```

Those should be same in order for `Service` to work.

Comment: I tryed this "serviceexample.javatechig.com.serviceexample.HelloService". not working

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the problem. the service tag in manifest.xml wasn't a child of application tag.If I showed the whole manifest.xml you would find the problem in a minute :)